# How to animate TextView and ImageView content change on android?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-animation

I have the following layout structure:

```
ScrollView
 - LinearLayout
   - TextView
   - ImageView
   - TextView
   - ImageButton
```

once user presses button, next record is read from the DB and displayed in according field.
How can I animate `LinearLayout` content change in such a way that it will look like activity change?

Comment: Can I apply setAnimation to ScrollView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented it in the following way:

```
private LinearLayout movieContainer;
movieContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll); // LinearLayout

Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left); 
movieContainer.startAnimation(anim);
```